# Cleanup the /var/lib/jenkins/caches folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

my jenkins caches(`var/lib/jenkins/caches`) folder is more that 8gb, I have to perform a backup of my Jenkins home directory.

Is it safe to delete entire files `/var/lib/jenkins/caches/*` or cleanup the `/var/lib/jenkins/caches folder`?

Will it affect my existing jobs?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, You should be able to delete all files under the caches. The cache directory contains data related to the git repository configured in Jenkin's job. Jenkins will caches the data again as you executed the builds depending upon the repositories used in those build by leveraging config.xml file of each job.

Comment: Awesome! That helped me resolve an odd Jenkins issue (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67920)

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to make the resulting home directory backup smaller, you could just exclude the caches directory from your zip. Something like

```
zip -r jenkins-home-backup /var/lib/jenkins -x /var/lib/jenkins/caches/\*
```